# pandas - explanation of unstack method description

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot

Please explain what the unstack function description  `DataFrame having a new level of column labels whose inner-most level consists of the pivoted index labels` means.

[pandas.DataFrame.unstack(level=- 1, fill_value=None)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack)

> Returns a DataFrame having **a new level of column labels** whose **inner-most level** consists of the **pivoted index labels**.
>
> ##### Parameters
>
> - level:  int, str, or list of these, default -1 (last level)
>   Level(s) of index to unstack, can pass level name.
> - fill_value: int, str or dict
>   Replace NaN with this value if the unstack produces missing values.

Suppose there is a long format dataframe.

```
def make_long_aapl():
    day_1 = dt.date(2015, 12, 29)
    day_2 = dt.date(2015, 12, 30)
    
    col_close = 'close'
    col_open = 'open'
    
    cols = ['date', 'ticker', 'attribute', 'value']
    
    rv = pd.DataFrame([
      {'ticker': 'AAPL', 'date': day_1, 'attribute': col_open,  'value': 106.96},
      {'ticker': 'AAPL', 'date': day_1, 'attribute': col_close, 'value': 108.74},
      {'ticker': 'AAPL', 'date': day_2, 'attribute': col_open,  'value': 108.58},
      {'ticker': 'AAPL', 'date': day_2, 'attribute': col_close, 'value': 107.32},
      {'ticker': 'MSFT', 'date': day_1, 'attribute': col_open,  'value': 106.96},
      {'ticker': 'MSFT', 'date': day_1, 'attribute': col_close, 'value': 108.74},
      {'ticker': 'MSFT', 'date': day_2, 'attribute': col_open,  'value': 108.58},
      {'ticker': 'MSFT', 'date': day_2, 'attribute': col_close, 'value': 107.32},
    ], columns=cols)
    
    return rv

aapl_long_format = make_long_aapl()
aapl_long_format
```

| index | date | ticker | attribute | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2015-12-29 | AAPL | open | 106.96 |
| 1 | 2015-12-29 | AAPL | close | 108.74 |
| 2 | 2015-12-30 | AAPL | open | 108.58 |
| 3 | 2015-12-30 | AAPL | close | 107.32 |
| 4 | 2015-12-29 | MSFT | open | 106.96 |
| 5 | 2015-12-29 | MSFT | close | 108.74 |
| 6 | 2015-12-30 | MSFT | open | 108.58 |
| 7 | 2015-12-30 | MSFT | close | 107.32 |

Is it possible to create a wide format dataframe below using the `unstack` method?

| index | date | ticker | close | open |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2015-12-29 | AAPL | 108.74 | 106.96 |
| 1 | 2015-12-29 | MSFT | 108.74 | 106.96 |
| 2 | 2015-12-30 | AAPL | 107.32 | 108.58 |
| 3 | 2015-12-30 | MSFT | 107.32 | 108.58 |

If possible, what to specify to the `level` parameter and what are `a new level of column label`, `inner-most level` and `pivoted index labels` in those dataframes?

> Returns a DataFrame having **a new level of column labels** whose **inner-most level** consists of the **pivoted index labels**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but first is necessary create `MultiIndex` for possible use `unstack`, because:

> Returns a DataFrame having a new level of column labels whose inner-most level consists of the pivoted index labels.

Here `inner-most` level of `MultiIndex` is `attribute`, so is used for new columns:

```
print (aapl_long_format.set_index(['date','ticker','attribute'])['value'])
date        ticker  attribute
2015-12-29  AAPL    open         106.96
                    close        108.74
2015-12-30  AAPL    open         108.58
                    close        107.32
2015-12-29  MSFT    open         106.96
                    close        108.74
2015-12-30  MSFT    open         108.58
                    close        107.32
Name: value, dtype: float64


print (aapl_long_format.set_index(['date','ticker','attribute'])['value'].index)
MultiIndex([('2015-12-29', 'AAPL',  'open'),
            ('2015-12-29', 'AAPL', 'close'),
            ('2015-12-30', 'AAPL',  'open'),
            ('2015-12-30', 'AAPL', 'close'),
            ('2015-12-29', 'MSFT',  'open'),
            ('2015-12-29', 'MSFT', 'close'),
            ('2015-12-30', 'MSFT',  'open'),
            ('2015-12-30', 'MSFT', 'close')],
           names=['date', 'ticker', 'attribute'])


print (aapl_long_format.set_index(['date','ticker','attribute'])['value'].index.levels)
[[2015-12-29 00:00:00, 2015-12-30 00:00:00], ['AAPL', 'MSFT'], ['close', 'open']]

print (aapl_long_format.set_index(['date','ticker','attribute'])['value'].index.names)
['date', 'ticker', 'attribute']
```

---

```
df = aapl_long_format.set_index(['date','ticker','attribute'])['value'].unstack().reset_index()
print (df)
attribute       date ticker   close    open
0         2015-12-29   AAPL  108.74  106.96
1         2015-12-29   MSFT  108.74  106.96
2         2015-12-30   AAPL  107.32  108.58
3         2015-12-30   MSFT  107.32  108.58
```

For this 2 function exist in pandas pivot:

```
df = aapl_long_format.pivot(index=['date','ticker'], columns='attribute', values='value').reset_index()
print (df)
attribute        date ticker   close    open
0          2015-12-29   AAPL  108.74  106.96
1          2015-12-29   MSFT  108.74  106.96
2          2015-12-30   AAPL  107.32  108.58
3          2015-12-30   MSFT  107.32  108.58
```